# Add Google Account to YouTube Analytics Access

Tags: analytics, youtube, google-plus

I work for an agency and I need to add the agency analytics google account to a client's YouTube channel so the agency account can see the YouTube channel and specifically access its analytics. How do I do that?

I have added the agency account as a "manager" to the YouTube / Google+ account of the client but when I try to use `Google Script` to call the `YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query('channel==clientChannel',....)` method. I receive a `Forbidden` error even though when I click through to the client channel I can look at the analytics page.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube channel will dilute these details. In my psyche, it's less demanding to join information sources as opposed to separating them later.

Step 1: Create a web property in Google Analytics

Before associating your YouTube in Google Analytics, you should make a web property for your YouTube channel. This will create a following ID that will be utilized to coordinate the two records.

Sign into your Google Analytics account.

Explore to the Admin area (situated at the upper right corner of the landing page).

From the administration page, open the Property drop-down menu (the center segment).

Click the Create new property choice at the base of the menu. 
Round out the suitable fields.

In the Website URL field, enter your YouTube channel's URL. (EG: www.youtube.com/klipfolio)

Click the Get Tracking ID catch.

Duplicate the following ID that is shown at the highest point of the page. It will look something like this:

Step 2: Enter the Google Analytics following ID into YouTube.

You should enter your Google Analytics following ID into your YouTube account keeping in mind the end goal to advise Google Analytics to screen information connected with your YouTube channel.

Sign into your YouTube account.

Explore to the Account Settings page (available by tapping on your channel symbol).

From the Settings Overview page, tap the View Additional Features connection. 
From the Channel Settings segment, select the Advanced choice (menu is on the left half of the screen).

Glue the Google Analytics Tracking ID into the proper field at the base of the page.

Comment: Please do not use your answers to promote your website